# Replacing apostrophe in string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using phonegap to share an article via WhatsApp.

The code for the button is as follows:

```
    shareArticle += '<li class="rrssb-whatsapp"><a href="javascript: void(1)" onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaWhatsApp(\''+$('.article_title').html().replace(/'/g, "&apos;")+'\', null, \'http://www.myaddress.com/showArticle-'+articleId+'\', function() {console.log(\'share ok\')}, function(errormsg){alert(errormsg)});" class="popup" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">';
    shareArticle += '<span class="rrssb-icon"><!-- Icon in SVG --></span>';
    shareArticle += '</a></li>';
```

The part that I'm asking about is this:

```
onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaWhatsApp(\''+$('.article_title').html().replace(/'/g, "&apos;")+'\', null, \'http://www.myaddress.com/showArticle-'+articleId+'\', function() {console.log(\'share ok\')}, function(errormsg){alert(errormsg)});"
```

The button is not working when there is an apostrophe in the title.

The strangest thing is that if I replace `&apos;` with `&quot;` it work perfectly (even thought the result is wrong).

Doe's anybody has any idead why `&apos;` fails?

Comment: I doubt it works this way since you have two double quotes. One where the `onClick="` starts, and where you do a `replace` (`"&apos")`.

Comment: Why not just `JSON.stringify(article_title)` to be sure it's properly encoded no matter what it is?

Comment: @putvande If you'll look at the first example the string is escaped with a single quote, so the second double quote is not in the string. Anyway, I already tried changing it. Didn't make a difference.

Comment: Yea I think there's some funky single/double quote early termination going on here. I just tried to work out where it was but it's too late on a Friday for  my brain to function correctly!

Comment: @tadman because the function requires a string, not a JSON.

Comment: @Digicom `JSON.stringify('test')` returns `'"test"'` as a string. It's not just for  JSON objects.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you all for your support.

The solution is to change the apostrophe to another sign that doesn't break the string.

So what I did is:

```
$('.opinion_content_title').html().replace(/'/g, "′")
```

Again, thank you all.

Comment: Very great solution.

Answer (score 1):

> The named character reference `&apos`; (the apostrophe, U+0027) was introduced in XML 1.0 but does not appear in HTML. Authors should therefore use `&#39`; instead of `&apos`; to work as expected in HTML 4 user agents.